# fetching rows without any filtered child row

Tags: sql, sql-server

The application manages (for the sake of simplicity) Topic and Messages posted to it by Users. Its structure is rather simple, and enforced by Foreign keys:

There are 3 tables, Topics, Users and Messages.

The Topic and User entities are linked through an (*,*) cardinality link embodied by the Message Entity.

```
Message: (IdTopic,IdUser,Message)
```

The other entities aren't of any interest by themselves.

Now the question:

I need to return every topics for which a specific user hasn't made any reply (Message). As you imagine, the database diagram is constitued of 3 tables.

How do I do it without a complex query? I am quite sure the answer is easy... But it's far too late in the night for me to think straight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Using NOT EXISTS

```
SELECT t.*
  FROM TOPICS t
 WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT NULL
                    FROM MESSAGES m
                   WHERE m.idtopic = t.idtopic
                     AND m.isuser = @userid)
```

### Using NOT IN

```
SELECT t.*
  FROM TOPICS t
 WHERE t.idtopic NOT (SELECT m.idtopic
                        FROM MESSAGES m
                       WHERE m.isuser = @userid)
```

### Using LEFT JOIN / IS NULL

```
   SELECT t.*
     FROM TOPICS t
LEFT JOIN MESSAGES m ON m.idtopic = t.idtopic
                      AND m.isuser = @userid
    WHERE m.message IS NULL
```

### Performance Concerns

NOT IN and NOT EXISTS perform better than LEFT JOIN / IS NULL if the columns being compared (idtopic, isuser) are not nullable.  See [this link for details](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/15/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-sql-server/).

Comment: Thanks, yes.. how didn't I think about it. Hem. The not in or not exists answers are perfects as I can easily return the message count in the query as well.

Answer (score 0):

From what you've described I believe that this query will work. I'm sure that it can be made to be more efficient, but I wanted it to work and be simple and then you could figure out how to improve it if you want.

```
SELECT t.IdTopics
FROM Topics t 
WHERE t.IdTopics NOT IN (SELECT m.IdTopics 
                          FROM Messages m 
                          WHERE m.IdUser = @SpecificUser
                         )
```